# Alignment indent

Tags: java, swing, alignment, layout-manager, positioning

How is it possible that the lines `question1` and `answer1` not appear UNDER the options block (4 options).
But instead, it is placed NEXT to the option lines in the middle?
How can I solve this

java

```
        Dimension d = new Dimension(500,500); 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Morgage company Rip off LtD."); 

        frame.setSize(d);
        frame.setResizable(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
        panel.setSize(200, 200);

        JLabel options = new JLabel("<html>For Lineair : press (l)<br>For Saving : press (s)<br>For Annuity : press (a)<br>For All forms : press (a)<br></html>");

        JLabel question1 = new JLabel("Type of morgage?"); 
        JTextField answer1 = new JTextField(); 

        answer1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Confirm"); 


        question1.setAlignmentX(0);
        question1.setAlignmentY(50);

        answer1.setAlignmentX(20);
        answer1.setAlignmentY(50);


        panel.add(options); 
        panel.add(question1);      
        panel.add(answer1);


        panel.add(button1);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: 1) `frame.setSize(d);` That's no better than a guess. If it turns out to be right on one OS, it will likely be wrong on others. 2) Instead add the components (with appropriate layouts) then `pack()` the frame to the correct size. 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 4) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 2):

> But instead, it is placed NEXT to the option lines in the middle?

Swing uses layout managers to position components based on the rules of the layout manager.

By default a `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout`, which places components on a single line next to one another. When the line is full, the components will wrap to the next line.

The `setAlignementX(...)` and `setAlignmentY(...)` methods do not position components at a pixel location. Those properties "might" be used by the layout manager to help with the layout. They are not used by the `FlowLayout`.

The solution is to use layout managers. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples.

You can nest panels with different layout managers to achieve your desired layout.

Also,

```
panel.setSize(200, 200);
```

that statement does nothing. The layout manager will determine the preferred size of the panel and in your case you add the "panel" to frame, which by default uses a `BorderLayout`. So the panel will fill the entire space available to the frame.